# Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Document'.ts(2339)

Tags: nodejs, typescript

Intento acceder a una de las propiedades resultantes de una consulta a un modelo con mongoose y no me deja acceder, arrojandome el error en el titulo (`Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Document'.ts(2339)`)

El error me lo marca cuando intento acceder a la propiedad **email** (`person_data?.email`)

El controlador lo tengo de la sig manera:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import Person from '../models/Person'

class PersonController {
    
    async getRandom (req : Request , res : Response){

        try {

            const person_count = await Person.countDocuments({})
            const person_random = Math.floor(Math.random() * person_count)
            const person_data = await Person.findOne().skip(person_random)

            const person_email = person_data?.email

            return res.json(person_email)
        } catch (err) {
            return res.json({
                message: 'Error',
            })
        }
    }

}

const personController = new PersonController();

export default personController;
```

El modelo lo tengo asi:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

const schema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'El nombre es necesario']
  },
  second_name: {
    type: String
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'El apellido es necesario']
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, 'El correo es necesario']
  },
  status: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

export default model('Person', schema)
```

Answer (score 1):

Habia visto varias preguntas y respuestas en SO pero no sabia como adaptarlas a mi codigo, consegui un blog bueno donde explicaba como crear una [**¿Como crear una REST API con TypeScript y Mongoose?**](https://medium.com/@keller.f.peter/how-to-create-a-rest-api-with-typescript-and-mongoose-b2a575a1dd4f).

Y mi modelo quedó asi:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from "mongoose";

export interface PersonInterface extends Document {
  name: string;
  second_name: string;
  lastname: string;
  email: string;
  status: Boolean;
  created_at: Date;
  updated_at: Date;
}

const PersonSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'El nombre es necesario']
  },
  second_name: {
    type: String
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'El apellido es necesario']
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, 'El correo es necesario']
  },
  status: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

const Person = mongoose.model("Person", PersonSchema);
export default Person;
```